# Set the DataGrid Header Text in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am using DataGrid as

```
 <DataGrid  Name="DgPreviousEntries" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TimeEntryGrid}" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeTimeEntries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTimeEntry}">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomHeaderTemplate">
                    <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskGridText, ElementName=SpeedColumn,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />                        
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>                 
                <DataGrid.Columns>               
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="SpeedColumn" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"  Width="150*" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TaskColumn}">                        
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                   
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

But i am not able to set the header text dynamically from C# property. Do i need to set any other property

Comment: is this silverlight datagrid?what do you meant by dynamic? code behind?

Comment: This is WPF Datagrid.. dynamic means code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple then,

```
DgPreviousEntries.Columns[0].Header = "Your header name";
```

In MVVM

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Data.MyTitle, Source={StaticResource Collection}}"/>
```

Comment: i need the same in MVVM

Comment: I Modified the answer

Comment: Yeah u r right, DataContext.PorpertyName is the key

Comment: i don't understand what Source is , what collection ?